# clear the current session after closing the tab or browser in the Firebase real-time database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, session, firebase-authentication

I want to log out the current session after closing the tab or browser in the Firebase real-time database in Javascript.

If I log in with my email address and password, copy the URL and paste it into a new tab, it always shows the current page instead of the login screen or (session logout). It should log out my current session when the state change when I close the tab, close the browser, or open the same page in a new tab it should always show a login screen.

```
 function login() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
        .then((result) => {

            alert("Login Successful");
            console.log(result);
            if (email.value == "abc123@gmail.com") {
                window.location.href = "dpr.html"
            } else if (email.value == "abc1234@gmail.com") {
                window.location.href = "gpr.html"
            } else if (email.value == "abc12345@gmail.com") {
                window.location.href = "cargo.html"
            } else if (email.value == "abc123456@gmail.com") {
                window.location.href = "admin.html"
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            console.log(errorCode);
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            alert("Please Enter the correct password")
        })
}
```

Comment: You've provided two scenarios: "_log out the current session after closing the tab or browser_" and "_...or open the same page in a new tab_" - which is it?

Comment: The session is undoubtedly cookie based - the session cookie is available to the domain. If logged in on one tab, navigating to the same domain in another tab will use the cookie and the related session in the new tab. The only way to accomplish your goal is to delete or disregard the cookie - but then all sessions across all tabs will be logged out.

Comment: @RandyCasburn after logging in. When I paste the same URL into a new tab, I always see the same page instead of the login page. It should show me the login page when I open the same URL in a new tab.

and when I close the tab or browser it should automatically log out or delete the session, which means that every time I reopen the page after closing the tab or browser it should ask for an email and password

Comment: this part: "_when I close the tab or browser it should automatically log out or delete the session,_" is easy. Use `beforeUnload` handler to delete the session cookie from the browser. BUT, this part: "_It should show me the login page when I open the same URL in a new tab_" is possible, but will required your users to log in on every single page request regardless of the tab they have open or are using. That is the nature of browser based sessions.

Comment: @RandyCasburn could you please guide me how can i use before handler in javascript? or share useful links please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication keeps the user's authentication state in local storage. If you want to prevent it from doing that, you can [set the auth state persistence behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). To have the auth state only be persisted to the current session, you'd do:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

See the documentation I linked above for a full explanation.

Comment: I tried this state but not working. Can you please tell me where do i have to place this state?

Comment: @UmerWaqas It should be added before the lines you really sign user in, so in your code just after ```var password``` and before ```firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword``` line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is 3 years too late but this helped me:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#web-namespaced-api

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(() => {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)